# How can i use static resources in WinUI3 pages?

Tags: xaml, .net-5, winui-3

In my last years release i used net core 3 and WPF like that:

```
<Label Content="{x:Static p:Resources.WJAJobtitle}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Now i'm trying to upgrade to net 5 with WinUI3. As far as i read, i have to use now TextBlock instead of Label. I read the docs, but haven't found anything about static resources.

Maybe anyone knows, how to set it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

As found [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/app-resources/localize-strings-ui-manifest) the new format for such things are:

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="WJAJobtitle"/>
```